# I am trying to install angular material i gave the command npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk, I am facing the below issue

Tags: npm, angular-material, karma-jasmine, npm-package

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: dex-web-ui@0.0.0 npm ERR!
> Found: @angular/animations@8.2.14 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/animations npm ERR!
> @angular/animations@"~8.2.14" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> @angular/animations@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.6
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material npm ERR!
> @angular/material@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!

I tried to update using the command npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk and seeing this issue.

> code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR!
> While resolving: karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 npm ERR! Found:
> jasmine-core@3.4.0 npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core npm ERR!   dev
> jasmine-core@"~3.4.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> jasmine-core@"^3.3" from karma-jasmine@2.0.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/karma-jasmine npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~2.0.1"
> from the root project npm ERR!     peer karma-jasmine@">=1.1" from
> karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter npm ERR!       dev
> karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.4.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> jasmine-core@">=3.5" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter npm ERR!   dev
> karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.4.0" from the root project

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue you can run the `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` this worked for me to upgrade the material version

Answer (score 0):

you need remove one of the two packages that conflict , I had the same problem with the package animations , I had installed version 15.2 and 14.1 , I removed the 15 via the command ( npm unistall @angular/animations@15.1.2 ) :

```
 npm unistall <package name>
```

in your case I think the conflict is caused by the package jasmine-core@ 3.5 , 3.3 and 3.4 , uninstall 2 package and should go

Answer (score 0):

This are the warnings which came accross when you're trying to install the package.

Just use `--force` to ignore the warnings.

`npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk --force`

Execute the above command and it will successfully install the material.